# Pronunciation of sedes

Tags: pronunciation

I typically pronounce *sedes* as SED-ays. However, I recently noticed that the "Holy See," meaning the bishopric of the Vatican, comes from *Sancta Sedes* (the Holy Seat), so if this is being rendered "see" in English, then the suggestion would be that it was originally pronounced SEE-dees, not SED-ays, at least in post-Renaissance ecclesiastical Latin.

Are there any definitive tracts on the pronunciation of this word type?

Comment: Have you checked this word in any [online Latin dictionary](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79)? Many of them indicate vowel length, and you can check several if you want more certainty.

Comment: The pronunciation of an English word derived from a Latin one is not, in general, relevant evidence for the pronunciation of the Latin word.

Comment: @dbmag9 Well, if somebody does research and finds out that in the 17th century, it was common for Catholic prelates to pronounce sedes as SEE-DEES and English people--hearing them say that--then used the word "see", then you would be wrong about that wouldn't you?

Comment: You piqued my curiosity enough to open [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/see#Etymology_2), where I found that the English *see* comes from Old French *sie*, from the Latin *sedes*. So my point that the English pronunciation is not relevant evidence for the Latin pronunciation does seem to apply in this case.

Comment: +1, but I think you could elaborate more. For Sancta Sedes I automatically assume Ecclesiastical pronunciation (approximately ['se.des], SED-ays), but you could be thinking about [_traditional English pronunciation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin) which was common until about one century ago and is kind of reviving e.g. in legal contexts.

Answer (score 3):

A few centuries ago, English went through the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift), which changed the pronunciations of all its long vowels. This is why we use the letters A, E, I, O, and U differently from pretty much every other language that has this alphabet. And as a result, the English pronunciation of a Latin word doesn't say much about its original pronunciation in Latin: pronouncing the borrowed word *lēgālis* as "LEE-gal" is purely an English thing.

In this case, the word most likely passed through French rather than being borrowed directly from Latin, so it's one more degree removed: there were a lot of sound changes (and a couple morphology changes) between Latin *sēdēs* and French *siège*, though the Great Vowel Shift would have given the same first vowel either way.